# Show $\langle \alpha| (\cos \mu)^{-a^{\dagger} a} | \alpha \rangle =e^{|\alpha|^2(\frac{1}{\cos \mu} -1)}$ for coherent states $|\alpha \rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-optics

I am reading "Quantum continuous variables, A primer of Theoretical Methods" by A.Serafini, page 120.

Let $a$ be the annihilation operator for the Fock basis.

> I want to show
>   $$\langle \alpha| (\cos \mu)^{-a^{\dagger} a} | \alpha \rangle =\exp\left[|\alpha|^2\left(\frac{1}{\cos \mu} -1\right)\right]$$ for coherent states $|\alpha \rangle$ and $\mu \in \mathbb R$

which amounts to showing equation (5.118).

The author says to use the Fock basis expansion of coherent states, namely
$$|\alpha \rangle =e^{-| \alpha|^2 /2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{\alpha}^n}{\sqrt{n !}} |n \rangle.$$
But inserting this expansion into the question above and using
$$(\cos \mu)^{-a^{\dagger} a}=e^{\gamma a^\dagger a} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\gamma a^\dagger a)^n} {n !}$$
where $\gamma=-\ln (\cos \mu)$ only results in a mess.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon multiplying the common factor $e^{| \alpha |^2}$, expanding the both sides yields:

$$lhs= \sum_{n,n',m} \frac{\bar {\alpha}^n \alpha ^n}{ \sqrt{n! n'!}} \frac{\langle n | (\gamma a^{\dagger} a)^m | n' \rangle}{m!}
\\rhs= e^{|\alpha |^2 e^\gamma}= \sum_{n,m} \frac{|\alpha | ^{2n} (\gamma n )^m}{n! m!} $$

Thus, it suffices to show

$$\langle n | (a^\dagger a)^m| n'\rangle=\delta _{n n'} n^m$$
which can be checked easily by considering even and odd $m$ 's separately.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: remember that $a^{\dagger}a$ is the number operator $\hat{n}$ and that the Fock states are eigenstates of the number operator.